# Создание баз данных через цикл

Tags: sql-server

Занимаюсь изучением MS SQL, хочу создать процедуру, при вызове которой можно создать n-ое кол-во одинаковых баз данных, разница только в наименовании. Но ловлю ошибку на самом начальном этапе:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createTable
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE createTable
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT = 2;
    DECLARE @a INT = 0;
    DECLARE @statement nvarchar(500);
    DECLARE @stmt INT;
    WHILE @count > 0
        BEGIN
         SET @a = @a + 1;
            SET @statement = CONCAT('Create table Student#',@a,' (name varchar(20), age int);');
            PRINT @statement;
            EXEC sp_prepexecrpc @stmt OUTPUT, @statement;
         SET @count = @count - 1;
        END;
END
GO
EXEC createTable;
```

Получаю ошибку следующего типа:

```
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure sp_prepexecrpc, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 20]
Не удалось найти хранимую процедуру "Create table Student#1 (name varchar(20), age int)".
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: возможно, стоит сначала почитать описание вызываемой вами `sp_prepexecrpc` ?

Comment: непонятно, о чём вопрос. в заголовке и в тексте — о созданни баз данных, а в приложенном коде описана попытка создания таблицы.

Comment: Стоит ещё задуматься над тем, что если вам требуется `n` одинаковых таблиц, то с вероятностью примерно `(n-1)/n` вы что-то делаете не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил некоторые моменты, так как под рукой у меня только MS SQL Server 2008 R2, но работать будет всё аналогично. sp_prepexecrpc - подготавливает параметризованную процедуру, а не выполняет динамический код. Пользуйтесь в таком случае просто EXEC-ом. И смените тэг на "sql server", а не "mysql" =)

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysobjects] WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[createTable]') )
  EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[createTable] AS RETURN')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE createTable
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT = 2
    DECLARE @a INT = 0
    DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @stmt INT
    WHILE @count > 0
        BEGIN
         SET @a = @a + 1
            SET @statement = 'CREATE TABLE Student#' + CAST(@a AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' (name VARCHAR(20), age INT)'
            PRINT @statement
            EXEC (@statement)
         SET @count = @count - 1
        END
END
GO

EXEC createTable
```